# optimize c++ query to calculate Nmin

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have run into a problem where i am trying to optimize my query which is created to calculate Nmin values for the increasing values of N and error approximation.
I am not from programming background and have just started to take it up.

This is the calculation which is inefficient as it calculates Nmin even after finding Nmin.

Now to reduce the time i did below changes reduce function call with no improvement:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<time.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

double f(int);
int main(void)
{
    double err;
    double pi = 4.0*atan(1.0);
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(7);
    clock_t start = clock();   

    for (int n=1;;n++)
    {
        if((f(n)-pi)>= 1e-6)
        {
            cout<<"n_min is "<< n <<"\t"<<f(n)-pi<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }       
    }

    clock_t stop = clock(); 
    //double elapsed = (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //this one in ms 
    cout << "time: " << (stop-start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << endl;   //this one in s
    return 0;
}
double f(int n)
{

    double sum=0;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sum += 1/(1+pow((i-0.5)/n,2));
    }
    return (4.0/n)*sum; 
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the time and make the second query efficient?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there are no errors, this is probably better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any immediate way of optimizing the algorithm itself. You could however reduce the time significantly by not writing to the standard output for every iteration. Also, do not calculate f(n) more than once per iteration.

```
for (int n=1;;n++)
{
    double val = f(n);
    double diff = val-pi;
    if(diff < 1e-6)
    {
        cout<<"n_min is "<< n <<"\t"<<diff<<endl;
        break;
    }    
}
```

Note however that this will yield a higher n_min (increased by 1 compared to the result of your version) since we changed the condition to `diff < 1e-6`.

Comment: Indeed it is. I'm just pointing out how to avoid the output which, depending on number of iterations, can take considerable time. After all, the question was about optimizing the example code.

Comment: sorry about that..basically i want to reduce the time in the second example.